# Ubunt 18.10 How to avoid the login-screen after resume from hibernate?

Tags: login-screen, hibernate, resume

When my computer, running Ubuntu 18.10, resumes from hibernate, I get to a login-screen, rather unlock-screen, that asks the password.

How can I avoid that so the computer resumes seamlessly?

Answer (score 2):

Try run this command in command-line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```

OR install GUI **dconf-editor**:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Run it: `dconf-editor`

Then go to `org/gnome/desktop/screensaver` and turn **OFF** `ubuntu-lock-on-suspend`

[image]

Comment: Hmm... I did that already. And still have the behavior that when returning from hibernate I get to the screen that asks my password. 

Not so after suspend. Then I get immediately to the desktop.

Sometimes when returning after hibernate I briefly see the normal desktop for one ore two seconds, but then I get to the unlock-screen and have to input my password.

Comment: Facing the same exact issue as you @Axel...